# Need to create a new node without redeploying nodes in Corda?

Tags: corda

I want to create a new node without redeploying my existing nodes in Corda environment . Is it possible to add another node from within the application without deploying it again .
If yes then how we will specify its ports for rpc and database .
For example : In my application I have a system in which there are different merchants and I want to add a new merchant to the system without redeployment .

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible (Imagine a configuration where nodes / actors couldn't join or leave the distributed ledger on demand ? That would be madness right?). All the active nodes communicate with the network map service so all your new node needs to do is announce itself to this and voila - the existing nodes are now informed.

I'm simplifying the process a little bit as we have gone through a revision of how this is done recently (and I don't want to give you the wrong answer), but depending on what milestone release you are running I can elucidate further.

Comment: We are using milestone M14.0-released .

Comment: @Richard Can you give a code example for version 1.0

Comment: Next question (to both of you) - are you running in "dev mode" or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Prior to Corda 2, you would be this as follows:

- Create a new folder containing the Corda jar and node.conf file, or make a copy of an existing node folder
- Modify the node.conf file to have its own web, RPC and P2P ports. Make sure you don't change the network map information
- Start the node by running `java -jar corda.jar`

  - You can optionally also start a node webserver by placing the corda-webserver jar in the same folder and running `java -jar corda-webserver.jar`

As long as your nodes are in dev mode, they'll auto-generate certificates if none are provided in their `certificates` folder. They'll connect to the same network map and be able to speak to the other nodes.

In Corda 3, you need to stop all the nodes and re-run the bootstrapper after adding a node or modifying a node's `node.conf` file. See the instructions [here](https://docs.corda.net/setting-up-a-corda-network.html#bootstrapping-the-network)