# New node to the existing Corda network has not seen

Tags: corda

I have working Corda network - Notary, NodeA, NodeB.

From the code nodes are available by

> List nodeInfo = rpcOps.networkMapSnapshot();

Next, I have to add a new node NodeC to the existing network. Without restarting all the network. I have tried the next steps - [Redeploying nodes in corda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467415/need-to-create-a-new-node-without-redeploying-nodes-in-corda)

New node NodeC started without any errors. But the network cannot see this NodeC. I think need to use specific service node for this aim. Any examples and best practice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Corda 3, the network map node was removed. Instead, all nodes need to be made aware of each other in one of two ways:

- By using the bootstrapper tool to copy each node's information to all the other nodes' `addditional-node-infos` folder. You can find information about running the bootstrapper [here](https://docs.corda.net/setting-up-a-corda-network.html#bootstrapping-the-network). Note that the bootstrapper is run automatically when you run the `deployNodes` Gradle task
- By creating a network map server that distributes information on all the network's nodes. See the protocol the network map must implement [here](https://docs.corda.net/network-map.html)

So in your case, you would need to stop all the nodes and re-run the bootstrapper tool. Once you restart the nodes, they will all be aware of each other.

Comment: Hello Joel. Thank you for your answer. I cannot stop running nodes. Just imagine, I have the existing and working node with 100 nodes. Next step, add a new node. I cannot stop all nodes

Comment: Agreed. When running a non-devmode network with hundreds of nodes, you need to provide a network map server that distributes information across the nodes.

Comment: When using a network map server, the nodes do not have to be stopped for a node to be added to the network.