# how to create a new corda network once user provides the number of nodes and there configuration details?

Tags: blockchain, corda

I need to create a Corda network when the user provides the number of nodes and configuration details of a node(like in demobench tool where we specify CoradX500name, location, ports) dynamically. we are using open-source Corda.
How can we achieve this? are there any gitHub projects similar to this requirement?

Comment: You could refer to this link. It might help you  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467415/need-to-create-a-new-node-without-redeploying-nodes-in-corda]

Answer (score 0):

**How to set up a Corda network with specified fixed number of nodes**:

```
https://docs.corda.net/network-bootstrapper.html
```

**Some key steps are listed for simplication:**

1. Download bootstrap tools from here:
   https://software.r3.com/artifactory/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/corda/net/corda/corda-tools-network-bootstrapper/4.3/corda-tools-network-bootstrapper-4.3.jar
2. Prepare node.conf file in a folder, like this:

   ```
     nodes/
      - notary_node.conf
      - partya_node.conf
      - partyb_node.conf
   ```

   in the xx_node.conf file, fill in the node information. You'd follow up this page for reference:

   https://docs.corda.net/corda-configuration-file.html?highlight=devmode#configuration-examples

   A minimal conf file may look like this:

   ```
   devMode=true
   myLegalName="O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB"
   p2pAddress="10.0.0.7:10011"
   rpcSettings {
       address="10.0.0.7:10012"
       adminAddress="10.0.0.7:10013"
   }
   ```
3. run the bootstrap tools to generate the network:

   ```
   java -jar ./corda-tools-network-bootstrapper-4.3.jar --dir ./
   ```
4. Enjoy Corda